# Struts2 with Velocity and Tiles

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, velocity, tiles

I am developing a web application on Struts2. For front end development I have decided to use Velocity with Tiles. I have found [Velocity](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/velocity.html) and [Tiles](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/plugins.html) plugins for Struts2 but haven't found any related article on using these three technologies together.

Can anyone please share there experience of using them together.